# How to find my OpenId from WeChat

Tags: openid, wechat

In WeChat I have an Id, **'MyUniqueId'**

For some reason I need to know my OpenId to using it in some requests to API.

Does anyone know how to find my OpenId from WeChat  ?

Comment: I am looking for the same. Did u found the solution for this. Is thr any API which gives me my OPENID.?

Answer (score 1):

OpenId is an id of a Wechat personal account when it is following an Wechat Service Account. And the OpenIds are different for the same Wechat personal account in different Wechat Service Accounts.

You can get your OpenId in a certain Wechat Service Account only if you are following it and you have the APPID and APPSECRET. See [this article](https://mp.weixin.qq.com/wiki?t=resource/res_main&id=mp1421140840&token=&lang=zh_CN) for the detail on how to list all the followers.

Comment: thanks for your answer,.. about followers I know how I can to get list of my followers,.. the problem is how to match openId returned from list of follower s with my list with WeChat unique id, in user details also I can get user NickName, but this nickName is not unique on WeChat.

Answer (score 0):

You need to log in to the WeChat public platform first. If not, please register an account first and find the appid path as Development -> Basic Configuration -> Development Information
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVpEy.png)